# Why won't this code run? I am confused

Tags: c++

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main(){
  std::cout << "Hello World\n";
  std::cout << add(3,4) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

// add.h
#ifndef add_h
#define add_h

int add(int x, int y);

#endif /* add_h */

// add.cpp
#include "add.h"

int add(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}
```

I am compiling with 'g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main'. I keep getting linker errors. I copied it exactly from a tutorial too.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp add.cpp -o ma`

Comment: You also have to compile add.cpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the add.cpp file is not properly linked.

What you need to do:

1. Create an add.o file by

   ```
   g++ -c add.cpp -o add.o
   ```
2. Link the .o file to compile

   ```
   g++ -std=c++11 add.o main.cpp -o main
   ```

Comment: Or you can simply add add.cpp by g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp add.cpp -o main

Comment: THANK YOU! Also what does the -c flag mean?

Comment: @RonB It means that the linker should just create an object file rather than trying to create an executable.

Comment: @JamesMaa I'd pop that comment into the answer. It will be more useful than the existing answer for most future askers of this question.